# FormatCurrency output

Tags: vb.net

Assuming `sngX = 67521.345`, What will be displayed when the line of code:

```
Label1.Text = FormatCurrency(sngX)
```

is executed.

Comment: Have you tried it?  Have you looked at the documentation [FormatCurrency Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3352e6f5%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your system regional settings currency sign is `$`, leading digits is false, and digit grouping is false, then `FormatCurrency(67521.345)` = `$67,521.35`

Since you haven't specified your regional settings, and haven't said that you want to use specific values for the other `FormatCurrency` parameters, your results may vary.

Comment: +1. Full explanation provided. Nothing else to add.